# Querying in Hbase can't find key because its got a hexadecimal in it

Tags: shell, hbase

Not much of a hbase guy so bear with me. Just a data analyst trying to do his job.

Let's say for the same of simplicity there's a hbase table called **Student** with the following info:

1. Key - Student ID
2. Value - SSN

So I'm trying to run the following command:

```
get 'Student_id','88812'
```

I'm trying to produce the following:

```
COLUMN                                        CELL                                                                                                                                                                          
H:00_ETAG                                     timestamp=1525760141144, value=1234567891
```

However, nothing yields. After scanning the table I've come to discover that the key has some sort of hexidecimal value in front of it. So the key is actually like

```
\x80\x00\x02F188812
```

I understand that in order to execute the get command I'd just need to use double quotes like this

```
get 'Student',"\x80\x00\x02F188812"
```

Now where the real issue arises for me is the fact that I have NO clue what the hexadecimal prefix for each of these keys should be. It seems like the table that I'm working out of has a different hexadecimal prefix for each key. Is there a way that I can somehow execute the **get** command without the hexadecimal or at least find out what the hexadecimal should be? How about doing a reverse search where instead I try and find the key by searching by value?

And no, I can't scan the entire table since there are millions of records that exist.

Comment: According to your comments there is no way! except full scan or get table schema from designer!

Comment: You should talk to a colleague who has experience with the table. You won't be the first person who wants to query this table.